# Download file prompt on localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-8

"To protect your security internet explorer blocked this site from downloading files to your computer" is message that I get when I want to download file from deployed website and it is causing me HttpException. How can I provoke IE8 to prompt me the same message when I run my web application locally. (localhost:4445) ??

Answer (score 0):

localhost is treated as a Trusted site and this allows you to download files without that prompt. What you could try (I have never tried it) is to use your IP address (but not loopback address 127.0.0.1) instead of localhost.

Comment: address of the deployed site is also among trusted sites